# iNEXT confidence intervals are very small

Tags: inext

I have formatted my abundance data for 138 vegetation plots of paired pre-fire and post-fire data for iNEXT by collapsing my count data into counts for all pre-fire and post-fire plots. Counts are in numbers per ha because the plot sizes differed between the pre- and post-fire sampling interval. When I run iNEXT and specify se=T and conf=0.95, I end up with very small confidence intervals that don't show up at all when I plot them using the ggiNEXT command. I am writing to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if these results are correct.

## calculate the rarefaction/extrapolation curve (R/E)

out <- iNEXT(master, q=c(0, 1, 2), se=T,conf = 0.95,datatype="abundance")
out

## Now plot sample-size-based R/E curves, separating by "time-step""

## and plotting the curve with 95% confidence intervals

ggiNEXT(out, type=1, facet.var="order", se=T,color.var="order") + theme_bw(base_size=8)

## calculate the rarefaction/extrapolation curve (R/E)

out <- iNEXT(master, q=c(0, 1, 2), se=T,conf = 0.95,datatype="abundance")
out

## Now plot sample-size-based R/E curves, separating by "time-step""

## and plotting the curve with 95% confidence intervals

ggiNEXT(out, type=1, facet.var="order", se=T,color.var="order") + theme_bw(base_size=8)

I would expect that these CIs would be larger, as they were when I did these analyses via Rob Colwell's EstimateS GUI software in which I was able to specify the results without collapsing the data into two columns of species counts (pre- vs. post-fire). I.E, in EstimateS, I was able to use all plot count data for all plots to construct the rarefaction curves and CIs. Any idea if these iNEXT results are plausible?

Comment: I think to answer this question, we will need a bit more information about your data. I have been working with the CI generated by iNEXT for rarefaction, which estimate the range in which the true mean sample diversity (given number of individuals) lies. They behave a bit oddly for richness when sample richness gets very close to true richness, but actually tend to be a bit conservative (too wide). _Important_: they do not indicate the range in which *true diversity* is likely to lie, only where the *expected sample diversity* given your true community and number of individuals.

Comment: Also, it looks likely that you are interested in using "incidence" type data, as occurrence in your plots, rather than average density per hectare, might be the units by which you'd like to rarefy.